# Double preview in windows explorer

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

This is what I see:

[image: Screenshot]

I use [QTTabBar](http://sourceforge.net/projects/qttabbar/), maybe that's why.

Answer (score 0):

One of the previews is when you hold the mousecursor over a file. This will only show up with .txt files though. In QTTabBar, this can be disabled by going to the options, tab `Misc.`, and then uncheck `Show Preview tooltip.`

Do note, there are 2 options with the same name. The bottom one is for sub folder information. You need to uncheck the top one.